Search an entire database for a string in PostgreSQL
I am working in Postgresql and am trying to find what table a specific word is in. For example, I am trying to find out what table the word "banana" is in. The database is agriculture and schema is fruit. Is there a query I can run that would return what table banana is in?

There is no way to do that except by querying all columns of all tables.

And is there specific syntax for doing that?

No, just the normal syntax: SELECT acolumns FROM atable WHERE acolumn = 'banana';.

Do a text data dump of the database using pg_dump -a and then do text search on that.

The following query will search for the value "banana" in all columns with a data type of either character varying or text in every table in the public schema:
WITH
  search_tables AS (
    SELECT
      c.table_schema,
      c.table_name,
      STRING_AGG(FORMAT('s.%1$I::TEXT = p.search_word', c.column_name),
                 ' OR ' ORDER BY c.ordinal_position) AS search_criteria
    FROM
      information_schema.tables t
      JOIN information_schema.columns c
        ON c.table_schema = t.table_schema AND
           c.table_name = t.table_name
    WHERE
      t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE' AND
      t.table_schema = 'public' AND
      c.data_type IN ('character varying', 'text')
    GROUP BY
      c.table_schema, c.table_name
  )
SELECT
  st.table_schema, st.table_name
FROM
  search_tables st
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL XMLTABLE('/table/row'
                              PASSING QUERY_TO_XML(
                                        FORMAT(
                                          'SELECT true AS found_it
                                             FROM (VALUES (%1$L)) p(search_word)
                                             CROSS JOIN %2$I.%3$I s
                                             WHERE %4$s
                                             LIMIT 1',
                                          'banana',
                                          st.table_schema,
                                          st.table_name,
                                          st.search_criteria),
                                        FALSE,
                                        FALSE,
                                        '')
                              COLUMNS found_it BOOLEAN) x
  ORDER BY st.table_schema, st.table_name;

Note that the search_criteria expression explicitly casts each searched column to type TEXT. This has been done so that the query can be easily modified to search non-text columns (e.g., JSON or XML). The cast has no adverse effects if the column is already character varying or text.
The function, QUERY_TO_XML, enables executing dynamically generated queries without resorting to procedural code (e.g., PL/pgSQL). Because of XML's low information density, QUERY_TO_XML is not practical for queries that return large data sets, but can be very useful for queries that return only a few rows.
Changing = to ILIKE in the search_criteria expression and passing '%banana%' instead of 'banana' to FORMAT in the call to QUERY_TO_XML will perform a case-insensitive search for "banana" contained within a column.
This query is likely to take a long time to execute if there are tables in the search space with a large number of rows. Modifying the criteria in the search_tables CTE to restrict the tables and columns included in the search space can help reduce the time to complete.

Not efficient, but you can do it conveniently by converting the entire table to json and check that:
SELECT 'mytable', json_agg(mytable)::text LIKE '%banana%' as contains_banana
FROM mytable

You can check many tables at once:
SELECT 'table1', json_agg(table1)::text LIKE '%banana%' as contains_banana FROM table1
UNION
SELECT 'table2', json_agg(table2)::text LIKE '%banana%' as contains_banana FROM table2
UNION
SELECT 'table3', json_agg(table3)::text LIKE '%banana%' as contains_banana FROM table3


Below is what you want that i had from ages ago. @tolookfor is your string and @matchstring = 't' (for true) or 'f' (for false) [dont ask it was a habit i got into!]
then it would give you a list of occurrences in a table and which column. which will narrow down your search.
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[DJH_Search_alltables_columns]    Script Date: 30/09/2024 16:51:31 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <null>
-- Create date: <14/06/2018>
-- Description: <Searches all columns and tables in target DB> 
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DJH_Search_alltables_columns](@toLookFor VARCHAR(400), @Matchstring CHAR(1)) --,@Is_int CHAR(1)
AS
BEGIN

--IF @Is_int = 't' BEGIN  
--  SET @toLookFor = CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(@toLookFor, char(0), ''))
--END


--create temp table
CREATE TABLE #result(
  id      INT IDENTITY,
  tblName VARCHAR(255),
  colName VARCHAR(255),
  qtRows  INT
)
;
DECLARE cCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
--get sys tbl and col names
SELECT
  '[' + usr.name + '].[' + tbl.name + ']' AS tblName,
  '[' + col.name + ']' AS colName,
  LOWER(typ.name) AS typName
FROM
  sysobjects tbl
    INNER JOIN(
      syscolumns col
        INNER JOIN systypes typ
        ON typ.xtype = col.xtype
    )
    ON col.id = tbl.id
    --
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sysusers usr
    ON usr.uid = tbl.uid
    --use xtype for back compat.. (finding only cols with string data types
WHERE tbl.xtype = 'U'
  AND LOWER(typ.name) IN(
        'char', 'nchar',
        'varchar', 'nvarchar',
        'text', 'ntext'
      )

ORDER BY tbl.name, col.colorder
--
DECLARE @tblName VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @colName VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @typName VARCHAR(255)
--
DECLARE @sql  NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @crlf CHAR(2)

SET @crlf = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

OPEN cCursor
FETCH cCursor
INTO @tblName, @colName, @typName

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
  IF @typName IN('text', 'ntext')
  BEGIN
  -- set up sqls when matched
    SET @sql = ''
    SET @sql = @sql + 'INSERT INTO #result(tblName, colName, qtRows)' + @crlf
    SET @sql = @sql + 'SELECT @tblName, @colName, COUNT(*)' + @crlf
    SET @sql = @sql + 'FROM ' + @tblName + @crlf
    IF @Matchstring = 't'
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = @sql + 'WHERE PATINDEX(''%'' + @toLookFor + ''%'', ' + @colName + ') > 0' + @crlf
        END
            ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = @sql + 'WHERE PATINDEX('''' + @tolookfor + '''',' + @colname + ') > 0' + @crlf
        END 
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    SET @sql = ''
    SET @sql = @sql + 'INSERT INTO #result(tblName, colName, qtRows)' + @crlf
    SET @sql = @sql + 'SELECT @tblName, @colName, COUNT(*)' + @crlf
    SET @sql = @sql + 'FROM ' + @tblName + @crlf
    IF @Matchstring = 'f'
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = @sql + 'WHERE ' + @colName + ' LIKE ''%'' + @toLookFor + ''%''' + @crlf
        END
            ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = @sql + 'WHERE ' + @colName + ' LIKE '''' + @toLookFor + ''''' + @crlf
        END
  END

  EXECUTE sp_executesql
            @sql,
            N'@tblName varchar(255), @colName varchar(255), @toLookFor varchar(255)',
            @tblName, @colName, @toLookFor

  FETCH cCursor
  INTO @tblName, @colName, @typName
END
--show results
SELECT *
FROM #result
WHERE qtRows > 0
ORDER BY id
END


Try SQL generating SQL.
The script below generates, for each column of type character string or text, a query returning <schema>.<table>.<column>, if 'banana' is found - for example:
SELECT QUOTE_LITERAL('banana')||' found in: ''public.frt.frname'''
FROM public.frt WHERE frname = 'banana';

... and it pumps that output right through yet another session with psql.
This is a test run's log: I have one table frt in schema public that contains 'banana' in column frname:
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $ psql -f findbanana.sql 
Tuples only is on.
Output format is unaligned.
'banana' found in: 'public.frt.frname'
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $

... And here comes the whole script:
-- tuples only output
\t
-- do not align
\a
\o |psql -At
SELECT
  'SELECT QUOTE_LITERAL(''banana'')||'' found in: '''
||QUOTE_LITERAL(table_schema||'.'||table_name||'.'||column_name)||''
||''''' FROM '||table_schema||'.'||table_name||' WHERE '
||column_name||' = '||QUOTE_LITERAL('banana')||';'
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema='public'
  AND (data_type ~~*'%char%' OR data_type ~~*'%text%')
ORDER BY table_schema,table_name,ordinal_position;

